# Redirection with useEffect() Not Working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-hooks

If the login is successful and a token is stored in localStorage, I should be redirected to a private route i.e /panel. If not, I should show the error message from ShowError().

Currently, my error message is being displayed if the login is not successful so it's all good. However, if there is a token present, there is still no redirection.

```
function LoginPage (){
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: '',
  }); 

 const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);
 const [shouldRedirect, setShouldRedirect] = useState(false);

function ShowError(){
  if (!localStorage.getItem('token'))
  {
    console.log('Login Not Successful');
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={colortheme}>
    <Typography color='primary'>
      Login Unsuccessful
      </Typography>
      </ThemeProvider>)
  }
}

// function FormSubmitted(){
//   setSubmitted(true);
//   console.log('Form submitted');
// }

// function RedirectionToPanel(){
//   console.log('check');
//   if(submitted && localStorage.getItem('token')){
//     console.log('Finall');
//     return <Redirect to='/panel'/>
//   }
// }

useEffect(() => {
    if(localStorage.getItem('token')){
      setShouldRedirect(true);
    }
  },[] );


  function submitForm(LoginMutation: any) {
    setSubmitted(true);
    const { email, password } = state;
    if(email && password){
      LoginMutation({
        variables: {
            email: email,
            password: password,
        },
    }).then(({ data }: any) => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', data.loginEmail.accessToken);
    })
    .catch(console.log)
    }
  }
    return (
      <Mutation mutation={LoginMutation}>
        {(LoginMutation: any) => (
          <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
            <CssBaseline />
            <div style={{
              display: 'flex',
              flexDirection: 'column',
              alignItems: 'center'
            }}>
              <Avatar>
                <LockOutlinedIcon />
              </Avatar>
              <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                Sign in
              </Typography>
              <Formik
                initialValues={{ email: '', password: '' }}
                onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
                  setTimeout(() => {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
                    actions.setSubmitting(false);
                  }, 1000);
                }}
                validationSchema={schema}
              >
                {props => {
                  const {
                    values: { email, password },
                    errors,
                    touched,
                    handleChange,
                    isValid,
                    setFieldTouched
                  } = props;
                  const change = (name: string, e: any) => {
                    e.persist();                
                    handleChange(e);
                    setFieldTouched(name, true, false);
                    setState( prevState  => ({ ...prevState,   [name]: e.target.value }));  
                  };
                  return (
                    <form style={{ width: '100%' }} 
                    onSubmit={e => {e.preventDefault();
                    submitForm(LoginMutation);}}>
                      <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        id="email"
                        fullWidth
                        name="email"
                        helperText={touched.email ? errors.email : ""}
                        error={touched.email && Boolean(errors.email)}
                        label="Email"     
                        value={email}
                        onChange={change.bind(null, "email")}
                      />
                      <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        fullWidth
                        id="password"
                        name="password"
                        helperText={touched.password ? errors.password : ""}
                        error={touched.password && Boolean(errors.password)}
                        label="Password"
                        type="password"
                        value={password}
                        onChange={change.bind(null, "password")}
                      /> 
                      {submitted && ShowError()}

                      <FormControlLabel
                        control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
                        label="Remember me"
                      />
                      <br />
                      <Button className='button-center'
                        type="submit"
                        disabled={!isValid || !email || !password}
                        // onClick={handleOpen}
                        style={{
                          background: '#6c74cc',
                          borderRadius: 3,
                          border: 0,
                          color: 'white',
                          height: 48,
                          padding: '0 30px'
                        }}
                      >                       
                        Submit</Button>
                      <br></br>
                      <Grid container>
                        <Grid item xs>
                          <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                            Forgot password?
                          </Link>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item>
                          <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                            {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
                          </Link>
                        </Grid>                    
                      </Grid>
                    </form>
                  )
                }}
              </Formik>
            </div>
            <Box mt={8}>
              <Copyright />
            </Box>
            {/* {submitted && <Redirect to='/panel'/>} */}
          </Container>
          )
        }
      </Mutation>
    );
}

export default LoginPage;
```

My App.tsx:

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

const PrivateRoute = ({component, isAuthenticated, ...rest}: any) => {
  const routeComponent = (props: any) => (
      isAuthenticated
          ? React.createElement(component, props)
          : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/404'}}/>
  );
  return <Route {...rest} render={routeComponent}/>;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component= {HomePage}></Route>
      <Route path='/login' component= {LoginPage}></Route>
      <Route path='/404' component= {Error404Page}></Route>
      <PrivateRoute
      path='/panel'
      isAuthenticated={token}
      component={PanelHomePage}
      />
      <Redirect from='*' to='/404' />
      </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you use useState to redirect? Just redirect directly. And if you are using `react-router` it is good to use `useHistory`.

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const history = useHistory();
useEffect(() => {
    if(localStorage.getItem('token')){
      history.push({
        pathname: '/',
      });
    }
},[]);
```

If you still want to use useState you can create a new useEffect NS add that state into your dependency array.

```
const history = useHistory();
useEffect(() => {
    if(localStorage.getItem('token')){
      setShouldRedirect(true);
    }
},[]);

useEffect(() => {
  if(shouldRedirect){
    history.push({
      pathname: '/',
    });
  }
},[shouldRedirect]);
```

Comment: I tried using the first method you suggested, and my page crashed: ```Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

Comment: Actually, as soon as I import useHistory, my visual studio file starts showing a yellow dot and when I initialise history, I get the error I mentioned above. so it all crashes

Comment: @a125 You need to put hooks into your component function before return template.